# Cannot add external javascript to a vuejs page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I want to add google translate widget to my page. When I try to add it in a normal webpage like this, it worked:

```
<div class="google_translate" id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'en'
  }, 'google_translate_element');
}
```

But when I move it to my VueJs project, it's not working anymore. I thought this might be because I the external script I added above not work, so I created a local javascript and try to link it to my page. But it's not work also. So what did a I wrong here? Im using VueJS and webpack for my application.

In my VueJS page, I put function googleTranslateElementInit to `mounted ()` and keep calling external script like in normal page

```
mounted () {

setTimeout(function (){ 
  $('.article-list').masonry({
    columnWidth: 208,
    itemSelector: '.article-box',
    fitWidth: true
  });
},0)
$("#menu-pagetop").on("click", function () {
  $('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 800);
  return false;
});
window.onscroll = function () {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > $("#menu").offset().top || document.documentElement.scrollTop > $("#menu").offset().top) {
    $("#menu-pagetop").is(".shown") || $("#menu-pagetop").stop().fadeIn(180).addClass("shown")
  } else {
    $("#menu-pagetop").is(".shown") && $("#menu-pagetop").stop().fadeOut(180).removeClass("shown");
  }
}
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'en'
  }, 'google_translate_element');
}
}
```

Comment: How did you add it to your vue project? You only showed how you added it on a "normal page"

Comment: @SølveTornøe I just put googleTranslateElementInit function into mounted hook. But i think the problem is the external script is not run

Comment: By function you "put" in mounted, do you mean `function googleTranslateElementInit() {...` or `new google.translate.TranslateElement({...`

Comment: @SølveTornøe `function googleTranslateElementInit() { ...`

Comment: Can you add the part where you put the function in mounted() to your question?

Comment: @Sirence I added

Comment: Why are you adding the whole function in mounted? You should add it under 'methods', then call the methods where needed.

Answer (score 0):

function `googleTranslateElementInit` is for google translate widget to use so you must make it scope accessable. Which means you should have something like below:

```
mounted () {
  window.googleTranslateElementInit = function () {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
  }
},
```

Here is the sample snippet, it shows some cross origin error. But it does work on my local

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  mounted () {
    window.googleTranslateElementInit = function () {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example">
      <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code seems working, by place the external script in index.html, but It only working for the first load of my component. The second time it got error `google.translate.TranslateElement is not a constructor`

Comment: The googleTranslatorElementInit is actually a callback for google server side to call. It passes arguments into googleTranslatorElementInit so it’s able to access google.translate.TranslateElement. You May try rewrite the googleTranslatorElementInit function to cache the TranslateElement function or the entire google obj then call that init function again with cached value when component reload.